# How would front-end developer turn this design into reality

Tags: css, user-interface, frontend

I see a lot of designers that make shapes on the website. For example, a curvy purple line like shown in here:  https://fiverr-res.cloudinary.com/images/q_auto,f_auto/gigs3/146762996/original/c5c40fc15550b852236414d3984f178e6b976e51/create-a-unique-and-creative-website-for-your-brand.png

My question is, assuming that I am a front-end developer and my boss gives me the files from the designer and asks me to implement this design into the website, how do I do that?

Is it just a one picture that I will get in many different width's and will have to use as a background and fit the text in with breakpoints?

Sorry if that sounds like a stupid question, but I always wondered about websites with weird shapes

Comment: go to the website, hit f12, inspect all the elements.

Comment: Every design requires a different approach. In this case probably several background images with content positioned over the top. I'm voting to close this as it doesn't really fit SO's question requirements.

Answer (score 1):

For "weird" shapes you can always play around with the clip-path property. Mozilla's dev tools give you awesome ways to play around with it and create a customized shape